# Ebay API CALL REVISEITEM NOT WORKING

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

[I am using ebay api and sending request to APIas XML 
i am sure i am not sending wrong values for compatibility still this error pop up every time i send API request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u7zY.png)

Comment: Kindly click the description to view the error screen shot

Comment: In order to help you it will be good if you can provide xml of request (response also better to put as sources instead of screenshot). As far as I can see there not correct user token provided when you try to revise an item. Also there some error related to User Policy using.

Comment: you are right token wasn't correct problem is solved now thanks anyway :)

Comment: i have one more query if you can help....right now i have have 500 item ids but after updating 94 item_ids compatibility .... api excess limited exceeded thats what i am getting.. what to do ?

Comment: better to make it as a separate question on stack overflow with XML request/response details.

Answer (score -1):

I could get the response 'succeed' with reviseitem API, here is my code, just use authToken. However, even if the response is 'succeed' the field I want to update is not updated. It seems this API does not work.

```
  const options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/xml",
                "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME": "ReviseItem",
                "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL": "967",
                "X-EBAY-API-SITEID": "15",
            },
            data: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <ReviseItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
            <RequesterCredentials>
              <eBayAuthToken>${authToken}</eBayAuthToken>
            </RequesterCredentials>
             <IncludeItemSpecifics>true</IncludeItemSpecifics>
            <Item>
            <ItemID>${itemId}</ItemID>
            <ItemSpecifics> 
           <NameValueList> 
            ${nameValueList}
            </NameValueList>
          </ItemSpecifics>
            </Item>
          </ReviseItemRequest>`,
            url: "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll",
        }
        const result = await axios(options)

        if (result.status === 200 && result.data) {
            const jsonResult = await parseString(result.data)
...
}
```